# convert base64 Image to Sql Blob in JAVA

Tags: java, base64, arrays, blob

I'm trying to convert Base64 to Blob in JAVA, I have developed this code so far and it's working but it's not a blob:

```
public static BufferedImage decodeToImage(String imageString) {

BufferedImage image = null;
byte[] imageByte;
try {
    BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
    imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(imageString);
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);
    image = ImageIO.read(bis);
    bis.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return image;
```

}

I think I have to convert bufferedImage to byteArray ? How can i improve my code ? And if i'm not even close how can i do it right ?

Comment: There's no need to read the image if you already have the bytes...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is my working solution for my question :

I had to convert my Base64 `String` Image to a `byte[]` :

```
public static byte[] Base64ToBytes(String imageString) throws IOException {
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(imageString);
return decodedBytes;
}
```

Hope this will help someone else .

Comment: You have asked how to convert to Sql Blob, and you answered yourself how to convert to byte[]. You have asked wrong question.

Comment: I'll explain to you what my problem was, i may have explained wrong, but i'm using eclipse Birt report ,  ihave a JSON object which contains Base64 encoded Images which i need to convert into Blob object to put it in my report.rptdesign, i asked for base64 to Blob because in birt the column image type is Blob, i tried your solution but it didn't work, so i tought maybe it needed bytes and it worked, anyway i'm only sharing this with people it may come helpful to someone

Comment: Your question should look like your comment, more detailed.

Comment: Anyway thank you for your answer it may not have solved my problem but it helped me .

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need a **SerialBlob**? like this:

```
import javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob;
.
.
.

public static SerialBlob decodeToImage(String imageString) {
    BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
    byte[] imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(imageString);    
    return new SerialBlob(imageByte);    
}
```

Comment: I have this as an output of the returned blob javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob@5e1ac263

I'm looking for Data presented like this
FFFFFFFF FFFFFFD8 FFFFFFFF FFFFFFE0 0 10 4A 46 ... 

how can i get the binary data ?